# CGSize width and height print as zero

Tags: swift

I want to know the width and height of image, but CGSize always returns 0.

```
let img : UIImage = UIImage.init(named: "icon_ear")!
NSLog("img w : %d, h : %d", img.size.width, img.size.height)
//img w : 0, h : 0 `
```

and

```
let cs = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
NSLog("cs w : %d, h : %d", cs.width, cs.height)
//cs w : 0, h : 0
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Try using %f or string interpolation, `print("w \(img.size.width)")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGSize's width and height are floating point and not integer.
Just change the format specifier from %d to %f.

```
NSLog("cs w : %f, h : %f", cs.width, cs.height)
```

Answer (score 3):

`width` and `height` are *floating point* values (`CGFloat`),
the corresponding print format is `%f`:

```
NSLog("img w : %f, h : %f", img.size.width, img.size.height)
```

The `%d` format is for *integers*. The full list of string
format specifiers can be found at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html.

The Clang C compiler would warn about the issue:

```
CGSize cs = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
NSLog(@"cs w : %d, h : %d", cs.width, cs.height);
// warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') [-Wformat]
```

but the Swift compiler does not detect that problem (yet). 
In Swift, *string interpolation* (as already mentioned in a comment) is an
alternative:

```
let cs = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
NSLog("cs w : \(cs.width), h : \(cs.height)")
```

but offers less control over the representation. 
When used with `NSLog()`, care must also be
taken not to interpolate strings which might contain format specifiers.